# Expressão regular, retirando valores do HTML

Tags: c#, html, regex

Tenho um HTML que eu preciso retirar os valores de um conjunto de `<li>`.

Essa é a parte do HTML:

```html
<ul id="minhas-tags">
 <li><em>Tagged: </em></li>
  <li><a href="/tags/tag1">tag1</a>, </li>
  <li><a href="/tags/tag2">tag2</a>, </li>
  <li><a href="/tags/tag3">tag3</a>, </li>
  <li><a href="/tags/tag4">tag4</a>, </li>
```

Quero pegar o conteúdo dos `<li>` como *tag1*, *tag2*, etc.

Depois de muito ler aqui eu cheguei nessa expressão regular:

```
tags/[a-zA-Z]+">[a-zA-Z]+<+
```

Isso consegue isolar o HTML que eu quero de todo o resto, mas eu não sei como transforma essa expressão para que ela ache os valores e retorne somente o conteúdo do `<li>`.

Essa expressão me retorna por exemplo: `/tags/tag1">tag1<`, e eu quero somente `tag1`.

Como eu faria isso? E teria como me explicar como funcionaria a expressão sugerida como solução, por favor?

**Atualização**

Desculpem, não coloquei a linguagem, estou usando C#, minha rotina é mais ou menos assim:

```c-s
public string retorna_Tags_HTML(string html)
{
    Regex ER = new Regex(@"tags?([\w]+)<\/a>", RegexOptions.None);
    Match m = ER.Match(html);
}
```

Comment: Qual a linguagem? talvez seja possível usar um *parser*, tente usar essa [regex `/tags?([\w]+)<\/a>/g`](http://regexr.com/3b3ml).

Comment: Linguagem é c#, esse link que você mandou retorna também o </a>. Coloquei mais informações na pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode-se utilizar a expressão [`tags?\w+(?=<\/a>)`](http://regexr.com/3b3po), que irá capturar qualquer palavra (entre *a-z*, *A-Z*, *0-9* e o traço inferior `_`) que estiver antes de `</a>` usando [*lookhead* positivo `?=`](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/modernosos-adiante.html#3_5_3).

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;
....

string html = 
    @"<ul id=""minhas-tags"">
       <li><em>Tagged: </em></li>
        <li><a href=""/tags/tag1"">tag1</a>, </li>
        <li><a href=""/tags/tag2"">tag2</a>, </li>
        <li><a href=""/tags/tag3"">tag3</a>, </li>
        <li><a href=""/tags/tag4"">tag4</a>, </li>";

  Match[] tags = Regex.Matches(html, @"tags?\w+(?=</a>)")
                   .Cast<Match>()
                   .ToArray();

  foreach (var tag in tags) {
        Console.WriteLine(tag.Value);
  }
  Console.ReadLine();
```

[Ver **`demonstração`**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8iu1Kl)

Uma outra forma seria usar um [*parser*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C3%A1lise_sint%C3%A1tica_%28computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29), como o [**`HTML Agile Pack`**](http://html-agility-pack.net/) para extrair essas informações, veja um exemplo:

```
string html = 
    @"<ul id=""minhas-tags"">
       <li><em>Tagged: </em></li>
         <li><a href=""/tags/tag1"">tag1</a>, </li>
         <li><a href=""/tags/tag2"">tag2</a>, </li>
         <li><a href=""/tags/tag3"">tag3</a>, </li>
         <li><a href=""/tags/tag4"">tag4</a>, </li>";

var documento = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
documento.LoadHtml(html);

foreach (var tag in documento.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a")) {
      Console.WriteLine(tag.InnerText);
}
Console.ReadLine();
// tag1
// tag2
// tag3
// tag4
```

**Nota**: É necessário referenciar o [**`HTML Agile Pack`**](http://html-agility-pack.net/) no projeto.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var html = document.querySelector("#minhas-tags").innerHTML;
var conteudo = [];
html.replace(/tag[0-9]*">([a-zA-Z0-9]*)<\/a>/gi, function($1, $2) {
  conteudo.push($2);
});
alert(conteudo);
```

```html
<ul id="minhas-tags">
  <li><em>Tagged: </em>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/tags/tag1">tag1</a>,</li>
  <li><a href="/tags/tag2">tag2</a>,</li>
  <li><a href="/tags/tag3">tag3</a>,</li>
  <li><a href="/tags/tag4">tag4</a>,</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Como eu faria isso usando c#, coloquei as classes que uso na pergunta. Obrigado.

Comment: Não sei =/, mas vê se troca isso: "tags?([\w]+)<\/a>" por "tag[0-9]*\">([a-zA-Z0-9]*)<\/a>"....

Comment: Coloque uma explicação textual na sua resposta para ajudar o Autor da pergunta e outros membros que chegarem na pergunta dele.